# Limit of derivative of $\exp(-1/x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

(updated) I am trying to describe the behavior of the function $f(x) = \exp(-a/x)$ at small $x$, and this includes also the behavior of the first derivative of the function. This would be simplified if there was some polynomial description of the function at small $x$. For instance, then it would be simple (in my understanding) to apply L'Hopitals rule when attempting to show that the derivative goes to zero as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Originally I wanted to expand $f(x) = \exp(-a/x)$ as a polynomial in $x$ and truncate the expansion as an approximation of $f(x)$ when $x$ is small. I have learned (thank you) that this is not possible in the limit of $x\rightarrow 0$ (the function is not analytical).

I am still left with showing that the derivative of  $\exp(-1/x)$  as $x\rightarrow 0$ is zero. For instance,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$$

and I am stuck trying to apply L'Hopitals rule to this.

The updated question is therefore: how to show (if this is indeed true) that
for  $f(x) =\exp(-1/x)$, $f'(x)=0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: For small $x$, $x^1, x^2,\cdots$ approach $0$, but $e^{-\frac ax}$ approaches $\infty$, so that would imply the zeroth coefficient of your MacLaurin expansion is $\infty$. Not to mention that $e^{-\frac ax}$ isn't differentiable (let alone analytic) at $x=0$.

Comment: It doesn't have a Taylor series, but it does have a Laurent series, namely
$$\exp(-a/x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{a^nx^{-n}}{n!}$$
I.e for small enough $x$, 
$$\exp(-a/x)\approx 1-\frac{a}{x}$$

Comment: @K.defaoite sure, that's the Laurent expansion, but the approximation is very bad when $x$ is small (the approximation gets better for large $x$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Fair point. I was being a bit careless.

Comment: that approximation is for small $-a/x$, meaning for _large_ $x$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for the clarification, I must have gotten confused.

Comment: Ok thanks. So such a polynomial expansion is not possible? What is the next best thing to approximate the function near zero? Would it help if one sets a tolerance for the absolute deviation from the original function?

Comment: @BuckThorn You cannot have a Taylor series at $x=0$ since your function is not analytic at $x=0$. In complex analysis, we say that this function has an essential isolated singularity at $x=0$. There is no simpler function that can describe the behaviour near $0$ other than the function itself.

Comment: Try a different approach. Approximate $e^{-1/x}$ over $[0, 1]$ in terms of shifted Chebyshev polynomials, see what you get.

Comment: BTW, $$e^z=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^i}{i!}$$ *always* converges for finite $z$, but it's not a practical way to calculate $e^z$ when $|z|>1$. For large $z$, you need roughly $i=ez$ for $\frac{z^i}{i!}\approx 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly is a question in flux!

At the moment the answer to "what is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}e^{-1/x}$?" is zero when approached from the right, infinite when approached from the left.

Following up on the question about the derivative, the derivative is $e^{-1/x}/x^2$, so still zero from the right, infinite from the left. To see this, work with the logarithm of the derivative.

Comment: Sorry, from the right!

Comment: What about the requested limit of the derivative of $e^{-1/x}$?

Comment: I tried evaluating directly but end up with $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{exp(-1/x)}{nx^n}$ where $n\rightarrow \infty$. I tried to use your tip (use the log) but end up trying to evaluate $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1+\log x}{x}$ which does not seem particularly helpful.